# Unable to view the successful report/index.html by executing java jar file from cmd in serenity

Tags: report, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity

I am unable to see index.html after the successful executing java jar file from cmd prompt.

Issue background :

1. When I am trying to convert the serenity project to java jar file
2. I am executing the same java jar file using command prompt it.
3. And it has been executed successfully with full test case
4. But It does not generate the index.html report in the target folder.

I have been trying to identify this blocking but not able identify the reason behind this.

Can you guys please help me on this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Kavi

Comment: Serenity report is generated from a serenity-maven plugin that hooks into maven phase "verify". Therefore,  when you ran the from jar file, the plugin was not triggerd --> no `index.html` file. It's better if there is a cli tool to do that, not depend on maven.